# Is it safe to move "ACCEPT state RELATED,ESTABLISHED" to the top?

Tags: debian, iptables

I've the following iptables configuration:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 11 packets, 604 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      127 11093 BLACKLIST  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2      127 11093 UNCLEAN    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3      115 10437 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
... followed by rules for state=NEW for running services like SSH
```

The chain `BLACKLIST` blocks some source-IPs.
The chain `UNCLEAN` drops packets with unclean TCP flags.
I like to move the `ACCEPT state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule (currentyl rule 3) as far to the top as possible for best response behaviour - but without loosing security.

As far as I know I can move the `BLACKLIST` two positions down, because it's sufficient to check it only for `state=NEW`. Once `established` it already passed the `BLACKLIST` check before and therefore the `ACCEPT state RELAED,ESTABLISHED` can be positioned before the `BLACKLIST` rule. Right?

Would you suggest to move the other rules? (i.e `lo` to top or somehting like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netfilter processes the firewall rules in order. For both security and performance you want packets to transverse as few firewall rules as possible before they are either approved or rejected.

Depending on default policy you may or may need the rule allowig all traffic on the `lo` loopback interface `-A INPUT  -i lo -j ACCEPT` and `-A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` as the first rule.

Having a statefull firewall with the `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` rule as the first on the external interfaces makes a lot of sense as that is traffic that has already traversed the firewall rules previously and successfully, making the connection approved and nothing is gained by processing those subsequent packets too. On most systems with any significant amount of legitimate traffic that rule will match the vast majority of packets.

You probably need the blacklist rule before anything that does grant access.

You then typically order the rules on the likelihood they're relevant, i.e. on a webserver you may want a rule that is triggered often such as `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT` to come before one that is triggered rarely, such as one allowing access to a management port from your office network.

Look at the counters every now and then to check and see which rules are matched frequently to confirm your configuration is somewhat sane.

Answer (score 2):

You can, I have related/established at the top of my iptables chain. It won't allow anything extra in, just anything related to established connections like high port responses or established connections themselves.

As to moving the others, all you've got to think about is it processes them like a list so anything that hits will be processed by the first rule it hits. You can move lo to the top as well but your other rules are probably unlikely to collide with the loopback rule, especially as they are about other destinations/sources.